# DATE/DATETIME column type attribute in ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: sqlite, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, nodatime

In ServiceStack OrmLite, is there an equivalent to the `[StringLength(xx)]` attribute to specify that a property should be mapped to a (SQLite) database colum of a `DATE` or `DATETIME` type?

I am using the excellent `NodaTime` types and using custom serialization (to ISO format) to get them stored in the database, but they are stored as `VARCHAR(8000)` so this is not as good as the BCL `DateTime` types.

Comment: You know that [SQLite uses storage classes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), not data types, right?

Comment: I do, but some tools to open a SQLite database may still rely on data types as hints to display the data; and of course if I switch to another DB provider later I'll be happy to have proper data types.

Comment: And in the link you provided, it even says that the affinity to store DATE/DATETIME should be NUMERIC, not TEXT...

Comment: You might want to try using [this project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime.Serialization.ServiceStackText/) which is specifically designed to serialize NodaTime types for ServiceStack.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, that is about ServiceStack.Text (json serialization).  This is different, because you need to map a custom value type to a particular storage type through ServiceStack.OrmLite.  That's a different problem, and a good question.